# PHP MicroTimer class error with phpliteadmin

Tags: php, sqlite, installation, configuration

I'm getting a `This page isn’t workinglocalhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500` error when trying to load phpliteadmin.php (See [phpLiteAdmin](https://www.phpliteadmin.org/)). Looking at the Apache log

```
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 527610] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sat Jan 07 15:16:21.081744 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 528031] AH00163: Apache/2.4.54 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jan 07 15:16:21.081776 2023] [core:notice] [pid 528031] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Jan 07 15:16:27.554033 2023] [php:error] [pid 528032] [client ::1:36282] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "MicroTimer" not found in /var/www/html/phpliteadmin.php:476\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/phpliteadmin.php on line 476
```

The file's permissions are `root root 644` just like my index.html and info.php files. Any ideas what this is about? I'm using the downloaded latest. Before, I installed from apt and it wouldn't see my config's given directory. So I'm at a standstill...

Comment: Did you install the patch(es) from [issue #401](https://bitbucket.org/phpliteadmin/public/issues/401/microtimer-class-is-missing-from-1982)? (Or use the latest development version as per comment in  that thread)

Answer (score 1):

The release version hasn't been updated in a few years, and does not support PHP 8.  Instead, use http://www.phpliteadmin.org/phpliteadmin-dev.zip

That link isn't obvious, it's found here, under the dev version.  Given that PHP 8 has been out for a few years now, there should be a note on this page making it clearer: https://bitbucket.org/phpliteadmin/public/wiki/DownloadLinks